# I am getting an error when i try to add mysql connector dependency

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, rest

i tried to add the dependency in pom.xml.here is the code i used.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

but i am getting an error when i try to run the server.the error is below.

```
Error reading file C:\Users\Rusiru\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector- 
java\8.0.15\mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar
C:\Users\Rusiru\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.15\mysql- 
connector-java-8.0.15.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Comment: put the error in your question, not a link to an image depicting the error

Comment: Can you post the details of that error dialog?

Comment: ok, so, did your build download the dependency, or did you just add it in the pom?

Comment: I added it to the pom.xml

Comment: adding it to a pom doesn't do anything. It's an update, or a rebuild of the project, that will actually trigger the download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Eclipse menu: `Project -> Maven-> Update Project...`

Rebuild all.

Comment: do you mean by right clicking the project > maven > Update Project?

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mysql-connector-for-java-how-to-install-in-eclipse-and-tomcat/

Comment: You can set the question as solved (green mark on the left of this answer)

Comment: @GiancarloRomeo Did you check the checkbox of 'Force Update' too?.. Upvoted